# Excel: For Each loop to copy and paste to form a table

Tags: excel, vba, foreach, nested-loops

I have a file that allows for 2 drop down lists to be selected and return the corresponding results. Now I want to be able to copy and paste all the results of all possible selections from the lists and form a table to store this data for historical reference.

I was able to write the code below which successfully loops through both my lists and copies the values to then paste them in a different sheet. However I can't get the code to loop through the columns so that it pastes each output in it's own column. I would only need it to loop through 50 columns (as that is how many possible selections exist between my 2 drop down lists)

```
Sub CopyPaste_Test1()

    For Each i In Range("Vendor")
        For Each j In Range("Footprint")
        
        Worksheets("Breakdown").Range("A2").Value = i
            Worksheets("Breakdown").Range("C2").Value = j
                Worksheets("Breakdown").Range("C6:C90").Copy
                    Worksheets("Last Week").Range("B4:B88").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
            Next j
        Next i
               
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
        
End Sub
```

Comment: IIUC, use a counter: `Dim counter As Long`. Then `Worksheets("Last Week").Range("B4").Offset(,counter).PasteSpecial ...`, then `counter = counter + 1`.